# C++ syntax error: Getting several errors expecting ';'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my first post/question on SO. I am following Bjarne Stroustrup's book *"Programming: Principles and Practice using C++"*, and I am trying to do 'switch'-statements. I am getting several syntax errors, like:

- error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'value',
- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string', warning
- C4552: '*' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect,

Also, every time I want to use the variable 'value' inside a statement, I get a:

- IntelliSense: expected a ';'

error.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 RC, and I am not sure why I can't run this program. I ran a very similar version of this a week ago on OSX, compiling it through the Terminal, and it ran fine. Is the IDE the problem here, or my code? I am sure this is just a rookie mistake, but I'm just not seeing the problem. I've gone through the code several time. I hope you can help me point out my rookie mistake here!..

Thank you all for any input, I sincerly appreciate it!

Here is my code:

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{

int value = 1;
double euros = 11.2;
double yen = 989;
double pounds = 14.2;
char unit = ' ';

cout << "Welcome to this DOLLARS-TO-OTHER-CURRENCIES Program.'\n'";
cout << "Please enter a unit, then followed by a value: '\n'";
cout << "(e)uros, (y)en or (p)ounds.'\n'";

cin >> value >> unit;

switch (unit)
{
case 'e':
    cout << value << " dollars in Euros is: " value * euros ".'\n'";
        break;

case 'y':
    cout << value << " dollars in Yen is: " value * yen ".'\n'";
        break;

case 'p':
    cout << value << " dollars in British Pounds is: " value * pounds".'\n'";
        break;

default:
    cout << "COMPUTER ERROR. DOES NOT COMPUTE.'\n'";
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines at the top:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

You are using `cin` and `cout`, but you haven't included the header that defines these names.

```
cout << value << " dollars in Euros is: " value * euros ".'\n'";
```

You want

```
cout << value << " dollars in Euros is: " << value * euros << ".\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I believe I am using a custom header file (std_lib_facilities.h) that defines those names. Also, include those at the top did not solve anything.

Comment: Have you fixed the problems identified in the second part of my answer?

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly! I simply forgot the <<'s. Very embarrasing - but thank you for taking your time helping me!

Comment: You should probably use `std::endl` instead of `\n` if you want a newline. Try: `cout << value << " dollars in Euros is: " << value * euros << endl;`

Comment: Thanks for that tip; it sure seems more tidier. I'll use this variant instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << value << " dollars in Euros is: " value * euros ".'\n'";
```

You can't just put `value * euros` between two strings like this. Change it to:

```
cout << value << " dollars in Euros is: " << value * euros << ".'\n'";
```

Same for other occurrences.